# Disable Ajax Views scroll behavior?

Tags: views, javascript, ajax

How can I disable the *scroll to top* behavior in an Ajax based View? Preferably, with Javascript.

The scroll behavior is triggered when running a search from an Exposed Form.

Answer (score 5):

The solution above is for Drupal 7. In Drupal 8, `hook_views_ajax_data_alter` is deprecated and was replaced by `hook_ajax_render_alter`.

For those of you looking for it, here is how to do it in Drupal 8 [(source here)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!form.api.php/function/hook_ajax_render_alter/8.2.x#comment-64395).

```
function YOURMODULE_ajax_render_alter(array &$data) {
  foreach ($data as $key => $command) {
    if ($command['command'] === 'viewsScrollTop') {
      unset($data[$key]);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution from an old [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1447332#comment-6437180).

The scroll behavior is added as an ajax command `viewsScrollTop`, you can unset it in `hook_views_ajax_data_alter`.

**Example**

```
/**
 * Implement hook_views_ajax_data_alter().
 */
function YOURMODULE_views_ajax_data_alter(&$commands, $view) {
  // Remove scroll to top behaviour from views ajax
  foreach ($commands as $key => $command) {
    if ($command['command'] == 'viewsScrollTop') {
      unset($commands[$key]);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```